# Keras LSTM accuracy stuck at 50%

Tags: keras, lstm, accuracy

I'm trying to train an LSTM for sentiment analysis on the [IMDb review dataset](http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/).

As input to the word embedding layer, I transform each review to a list of indices (that corresponds to word index in the vocabulary set). I thought of converting the text into one-hot/count matrix, but I will end up with huge sparse matrix (should I worry about this?).

Here is how I am creating the network architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(
    input_dim=vocab_size,
    output_dim=word_embed_vector_size,
    input_length=sentence_len_max)
         )
model.add(LSTM(units=1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', 'binary_accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Here is the model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, 1422, 4)           201764    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 1)                 24        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 2         
=================================================================
Total params: 201,790
Trainable params: 201,790
Non-trainable params: 0
___________________________
```

Now when I try to train the model I see accuracy stuck at 50%

```
losses = model.fit(
    x                = term_idx_train,
    y                = y_train,
    epochs           = epochs,
    batch_size       = batch_size,
    validation_split = 0.01
)
```

Here is the epochs output:

```
Epoch 1/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 1148s 46ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 1156s 46ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 1149s 46ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 4/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 1110s 44ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 5/10
16800/25000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 6:10 - loss: 7.9816 - acc: 0.4993 - binary_accuracy: 0.4993
```

Changing the activation function to a `sigmoid` and the LSTM blocks to 32 didn't help mush (with 1 epoch):

```
Train on 24750 samples, validate on 250 samples
Epoch 1/1
24750/24750 [==============================] - 1186s 48ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.5022 - binary_accuracy: 0.5022 - val_loss: 0.6951 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.69513, saving model to sentiment_model
```

Looking at what the LSTM is predicting, I see:

```
count   25000.000000
mean    0.499023
std 0.000013
min 0.499010
25% 0.499010
50% 0.499010
75% 0.499010
max 0.499443
```

Any idea why it's doing this? and how I could fix the issue?

Comment: Can you please explain why did you decide to use 1 unit in the LSTM layer?

Comment: trying to output one element that could represent the review do you recommend something else?

Comment: The output is based on your last dense layer's neuron, and not the LSTM's neuron. I recommend increasing the LSTM neurons to, somewhere around 32, or 16, and then try to compare the results.

Comment: ok will try increase the lstm output, but is it normal that all epochs output seem loss and accuracy??

Comment: When you're getting same loss and accuracy for each epoch, it means that your optimizer isn't updating the weights anymore, and it appears to be stuck at some local minima, perhaps. So, it is a common problem which needs to be addressed. Try with different optimizers, a bit more architectural changes.

Comment: One more thing, even tho your problem is a binary classification, it'll still be a reasonable approach that you one-hot-encode your binary featuers, e-g [1, 0] for positive, [0, 1] for negative, and then have two neurons in the dense layer with softmax activation. As per my experience, that also worked reasonably good.

Comment: @SyedAliHamza are you sure about the encoding of the labels? I was sure that the problem would be the same and it wouldn't improve the classification.

Comment: Try a very low learning rate, say 1e-6. This ciuld happen by diverging. Also try to reset the weights and reshuffle. May be a local minimum.

Comment: Playing with learning rates, adding dropout layers did not help. But looking at the prediction above, I feel like it's predicting 0 all the time, which is 50% of the data and thus a 50% accuracy, no?

Answer (score 2):

**activation = ‘softmax’** should be used for multiclass classification whereas **’sigmoid’** for binary classification.

You can refer to: http://dataaspirant.com/2017/03/07/difference-between-softmax-function-and-sigmoid-function/

If changing the activation function does not help, I will be around for alternative solutions.

Comment: It didn't help much, still have bad accuracy; I updated the the question above.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a simple error you did in the code (maybe while extracting the dataset) that we can't see in your code sample. The constant loss you showed is a very weird behaviour indeed.

*Anyway...*

You are trying something really ambitious without a pre-trained embedding like *word2vec* and an architecture so simple.

I suggest you to give a look at my github [repo](https://github.com/SqrtPapere/SentimentAnalysis_CNN#random-idea-from-convolutional-neural-networks-for-sentence-classification-by-yoon-kim) where (if you are really interested in not using pre-trained embedding) there is an example that starts with **random** embedding and adjust it while training reaching `87.72%` on the TestSet with a CNN. You can easily convert it to LSTM.

Comment: As of the data preprocessing, I'm passing to the embedding layer a list of word indices, I thought with one hot encoding the sentences will end up creating a huge sparse matrix.

Comment: the list of indices is not a very good idea because you are giving an arbitrary ordering to the words! And yes you are right with one-hot-encoding you would end up with a big sparse matrix. But you can try! I still think the best approach would be to use random vectors for the embedding of the words.

Comment: I thought that if I don't provide `weights` to the `Embedding` it will learn them and they will be initialized randomly, isn't the case?

Answer (score 2):

With Softmax as activation in final layer, you should have n neurons, where n is the number of classes.
Here is an explanation: 
https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/multi-class-neural-networks/softmax
So basically:

```
model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

If you are using one hot encoding:

```
model.add(Dense(y_train[1], activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was related to the `output_dim` of the `Embedding` layer which was first `4`, increasing this to up to `16` helped the accuracy to takeoff to around 96%.

The new problem is the network started overfitting, adding `Dropout` layers helped reducing this.